# When trying to log into our blog, I get a message that says "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: bug, community-blog

When I try to log into our blog, it doesn't log me in right away, rather it takes time to load, and then it [says](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/seAuthentication/seAuthenticationLogin.php?reauth=1) :

> "The page isn't redirecting properly   Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete."

so then when I retype/go to "islam.blogoverflow.com" I find I am already logged in.  I believe this to be an error, for I do not get logged right in like I would log into this site, rather I first see the message I mentioned above.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is that the whole message, or is there more?

Comment: @Daniel I am using Firefox, and that was the main message, it did give me possibilities like I disabled my cookies, which I did not, it also gives the option of trying again.  I edited my question to add another part of the message, below the main one.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cookies and clearing the cache?

Comment: @Daniel Yes I did.

Comment: This is indeed a sort of bug - I redirect properly myself when I log in. Anyone else running into this issue, of those who are in the blog now?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this has to do with the Arabic part of your username. The login process involves a series of URL forwards and the way the URL is encoded in Wordpress is not terribly consistent. I believe the mix and match alphabet of your username is throwing it off. The server side stuff gets done, but getting you sent back to the right place is jamming.

Likewise, viewing your author profile as a non-logged in user is showing up as a 404. This might be a configuration issue with Wordpress, but it could also be related to your username encoding.

Comment: I have removed the Arabic part of my nickname, but it still gives me trouble when I log in, as well as my author profile still shows a 404.

Comment: @AlUmmatمجاهد You have removed it from your display name, but it is, for some reason, still part of your author URL. Even the link from the display name that doesn't have the Arabic links to a URL with Arabic in it.

Comment: I am unsure of how to fix that, I edited the Arabic part of my name out on this site thinking that perhaps it would update my profile on the blog, but it still seems to be part of the URL as you say.